# Can I split system.serviceModel into a separate .config file?

Tags: wcf, web-config, asp.net-3.5

I want to separate my system.serviceModel section of the web.config into a separate file to facilitate some environment settings.  My efforts have been fruitless.  When I attempt it using this method.  The wcf code throws an exception: "The type initializer for 'System.ServiceModel.ClientBase `1` threw an exception.  Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Web.config:

```
<configuration>
  <system.serviceModel configSource="MyWCF.config" />
  ....
```

MyWCF.config:

```
  <system.serviceModel>
    <extensions>
      ...
    </extensions>

    <bindings>
      ...
    </bindings>

    <behaviors>
      ...
    </behaviors>

    <client>
       ...
    </client>

  </system.serviceModel>
```

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You cannot "externalize" the `<system.serviceModel>` section group - since it's a configuration section *group* - but you can definitely externalize each of the bits inside it:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors configSource="behaviors.config" />
    <bindings configSource="bindings.config" />
    <extensions configSource="extensions.config" />
    <client configSource="client.config" />
    <services configSource="services.config" />
</system.serviceModel>
```

In the .NET configuration system, *any* configuration section can be externalized - each configuration section has a `configSource` attribute (even though Visual Studio sometimes complains and claims the contrary.....) - but not configuration section groups.

Unfortunately, these two are hard to tell apart - you need to consult the MSDN library or documentation to find out.

You should also check out Jon Rista's three-part series on the .NET configuration system up on CodeProject.

- [Unraveling the mysteries of .NET 2.0 configuration](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/mysteriesofconfiguration.aspx)
- [Decoding the mysteries of .NET 2.0 configuration](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/mysteriesofconfiguration2.aspx)
- [Cracking the mysteries of .NET 2.0 configuration](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/mysteriesofconfiguration3.aspx)

Highly recommended, well written and extremely helpful!

Comment: Nice tip... this section can get really busy.

Answer (score 6):

Try this suggestion:

http://weblogs.asp.net/cibrax/archive/2007/07/24/configsource-attribute-on-system-servicemodel-section.aspx

Comment: Thanks, the example in that article is more complete than in the other answer.