# Can I keep httpBinding off from client app when referencing another webservice in WCF?

Tags: c#, wcf, web-services

I have WCF service and in the resource layer I have a reference to outer web-service. It only works when I copy the httpBinding configuration to the client app.config. Otherwise  it will produce an error:

"Could not find default endpoint element that references contract"

The reason for wanting to do it is that I don't want to expose the 3rd party web-service to someone that want's to use my WCF service.

Can I keep the binding configuration in the resource .config file or maybe in the wcf Host project .config file ?

Comment: Nothing that your web service calls will be available for the cilent of your web service to call unless you explicitly provide methods that pass through to the third-party service.  What's in the client part of your service's config won't be exposed in your WSDL; only what's in the service part.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I fully understand the question, but you can always create the binding in code:

```
CustomBinding b = new CustomBinding()
//configure b
//...
Proxy p = new Proxy(b, "http://")
```

Comment: I kind like adding the connectionstring in the client .config when using database connection in WCF service ...but in this case i'm talking about the httpBinding elements that are added to config file when adding a web reference.

Comment: you can remove them from config and add them to your code (or maybe I did not get the question)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your scenario correctly, you want to point your app.config file to another “resource” config file that contains the WCF service / binding information.

As such, I think the following link details a solution:
[Can I split system.serviceModel into a separate .config file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2813975/can-i-split-system-servicemodel-into-a-separate-config-file)