# How to use dll's .config file when referencing a service?

Tags: c#

I'm aware of the fact that if the code in a `.dll` wants to read its configuration file it should have to do it manually. But what if (in the same `.dll`) you're referencing a service, that would scaffold some code and will add some configuration to the `.config` file, so the only way I was able to use the service was copying that configuration to the main app's `.config` file.

I'd like to know if somenone have another way to that. I think it should be using any of the constructors supplied by the scaffold but couldn't made it to work.

These are the constructors:

```
MyServiceClient(string endpointConfigurationName)
MyServiceClient(string endpointConfigurationName, string remoteAddress)
MyServiceClient(string endpointConfigurationName, EndpointAddress remoteAddress)
MyServiceClient(Binding binding, EndpointAddress remoteAddress)
```

And the configuration:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="BasicEndPoint" />
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="<service-url>"
          binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicEndPoint"
          contract="<contract>" name="BasicEndPoint" />
    </client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Question was bit confusing to me but what I understand is that you want some common config that stay in DLL config as well as when same DLL is being used by some other application. If it is limited to WCF then answer to question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2813975/can-i-split-system-servicemodel-into-a-separate-config-file will help you

Comment: When I was faced with the same problem I've used the last constructor: `MyServiceClient(Binding binding, EndpointAddress remoteAddress)`. Passed the service uri as a parameter in the class constructor and then just used the default settings.

Comment: @dotnetstep Yes, I should have explained a little about my solution's arquitecture. Thanks, I'll take a look at the link you provided.

Comment: @ZoharPeled I tried it but didn't work. Could you provide me some sample? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I was faced with the same problem I've used the last constructor:
`MyServiceClient(Binding binding, EndpointAddress remoteAddress)`. Passed the service uri as a parameter in the class constructor and then just used the default settings:

```
private MyServiceClient = _service;

public MyClass(string serviceUri)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(serviceUri))
    {
        _service = new MyServiceClient();
    }
    else
    {
        var binding = new System.ServiceModel.BasicHttpBinding() { MaxReceivedMessageSize = int.MaxValue };
        var endpoint = new System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress(serviceUri);
        _service = new MyServiceClient (binding, endpoint);
    }
}
```

However, I wasn't aware of the fact that you can externalize config files as demonstrated in [Marc_s's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2814286/3094533) (also linked in the comment by dotnetstep) - If I was aware of that, I might have used that instead.

btw, note that in my code, if you pass null or an empty string, the `serviceModel` is expected to be found in the config file.

Comment: Externalizing should be done also in main app's config file, right?

Comment: Yes, I think so. Didn't check it but it seems logical.